# Questions about Margin in the Futures

Tags: futures, margin, online-trading, margin-call

(I'm beginner)
1- Can I buy/pay the whole contract price without margin (the broker will have no risk at all then- no need for maintenace margin) ?
2- Is this borrowing money so I need to pay interest and regular fees? if not; What does the broker benefit from it?
3- Is the margin calls money I pay unrecovered so I lose money every margin call?

Comment: I've never traded futures so these are a noob questions

Comment: Futures contracts on commodities can go below 0 (CL crude oil did last year).

Answer (score 1):

Once you take a contract position, you can **win** or **lose** generally an *infinite* amount of money.  The price you pay to get in to the contract has nothing to do with anything.  Once you are in the contract, you can **win** or **lose** generally an *infinite* amount of money.  Margin sits there to cover you when you lose.